# Why HttpListener faster than Kestrel for serving large files

Tags: asp.net, linux, .net-6.0

All the server is doing is serving 20mb file.

HttpListener implementation:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Run();
    }

    public static async Task Run()
    {
        var _listener = new HttpListener();
        _listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000/bla/");
        _listener.Start();
        using (var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var _cancellation = cancellation;
            while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var context = await _listener.GetContextAsync();
                Process(context);
            }
        }
    }

     private static async Task Process(HttpListenerContext context)
     {
        var response = context.Response;
        using (response)
        {
        using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open("20mbfile", FileMode.Open,  FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                response.ContentLength64 = SourceStream.Length;
                var BufferSize = 40960;
                await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(response.OutputStream, BufferSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running `./bombardier-linux-amd64 http://localhost:5000/bla -t 80s -c 120 -n 700`  finishes within 7-8 seconds.

Here is Kestrel implementation:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole());
        await builder.Configure(app => app.Run(Process)).UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = null;
                })
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
        .Build().RunAsync();
    }

    public static async Task Process(HttpContext c){
        try{
            var BufferSize = 40960;
            var response = c.Response;
            using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open("20mbfile", FileMode.Open,  FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                response.ContentLength = SourceStream.Length;
                await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(response.Body, BufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
                 {
                       Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                 }
    }
}
```

Running `./bombardier-linux-amd64 http://localhost:5000/bla -t 80s -c 120 -n 700`  finishes within 14-15 seconds.

Bombardier runs locally for every test. On Linux.

Is there a configuration that optimizes Kestrel performance with large files? Or perhaps the tests are not indicative?

Comment: @LexLi Removing logging had no effect on performance. Is there a way to  disable all Kestrel middleware?

Comment: Took another look of your code and I think I was wrong on that part. The actual faster file transfer you observed from `HttpListener` might come from HTTP.sys. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-7.0 ASP.NET Core can hook to that as well to achieve "direct file transmission".

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for the comment. I just edited the question and added the fact that I run on Linux, so using HttpSys throwing `Unable to load shared library 'httpapi.dll'` error.

Comment: @Farseer `Kestrel` is cross platform while `Http.sys` only works in windows. Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows)